# Is there a way to get spring assistant plugin installed in IntelliJ 2022.2 version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm looking for `Spring Assistant` plugin for my IntelliJ IDE 2022.2 version but couldn't find it anywhere in the marketplace of IntelliJ or other sources, links from stackoverflow for this version. Tried `Spring Boot Assistant` plugin but of no use as I cannot see the option after installing plugin and restarting IDE.

[image]

[image]

Version which I'm using now
[image]

Expected option highlighted in red (pic from internet)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

this plugin is available in Ultimate edition of IntelliJ
not for the community edition of Intellij
thats why you are not getting it.

Comment: It is enabled for IntelliJ CE as well in the previous versions before they stopped the support

Comment: this link clear your doubt https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html